# PyQT5: how to automatically align the widget in QGridLayout?

Tags: layout, pyqt5

I am using QGridLayout in my project. I will automatically add some widgets in QGridLayout. Thus, I implement a class `MultiWidgetLayout` to manager the widget. My test code is:

```py
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
class MultiWidgetLayout(QGridLayout):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setSpacing(0)
        self.setContentsMargins(1,1,1,1)
        self.__widgets = []

    def getWidgetNum(self):
        return len(self.__widgets)

    def addWidget(self, widget):
        self.__widgets.append(widget)
        self.updateLayout()

    def setWidgets(self, widgets):
        self.__widgets = widgets
        self.updateLayout()

    def updateLayout(self):
        self.removeAllWidgets()
        n = len(self.__widgets)
        columns = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(n)))
        rows = n//columns

        k = 0
        for r in range(rows):
            for c in range(columns):
                super().addWidget(self.__widgets[k], r, c)
                k += 1
        remain = n - columns*rows
        if remain > 0:
            for r in range(remain):
                super().addWidget(self.__widgets[k], rows, r)
                k += 1

        for widget in self.__widgets:
            widget.show()

    def removeAllWidgets(self):
        '''
        remove all the widgets
        '''
        N = self.count()
        for i in range(N-1,-1,-1):
            item = self.itemAt(i) # item is QHBoxLayout
            self.removeItem(item)
            # self.removeWidget(item)

        for widget in self.__widgets:
            widget.hide()

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.multiWidgetLayout = MultiWidgetLayout()
        self.btn = QPushButton('add widget')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.addWidgetSlot)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        layout.addLayout(self.multiWidgetLayout)

    def addWidgetSlot(self, check=False):
        num = self.multiWidgetLayout.getWidgetNum()
        label = QLabel(str(num))
        label.setStyleSheet('border: 2px solid red;')
        label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.multiWidgetLayout.addWidget(label)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

This code basically fullfile what I want, but there still be a small problem.

When I add three widgets, the layout is:

[image]

However, I want the QLabel(2) occupy the whole space of the bottom row.

The layout of 5 widgets is:

[image]

But, I hope QLable(3) and QLabel(4) occupy the whole space of the bottom row.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: That would be tricky: what if you add widgets that have different minimum/maximum sizes or size policies?

Comment: The policy of all widgets should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the widgets are going to have similar sizes, hints and policies, you can add any remaining widgets to a horizontal layout that is placed at the last row, spanning all columns.

Consider that there is no need to remove widgets and add them again, since `addWidget()` automatically *replaces* their position in the layout and reparents them whenever required, which also makes unnecessary to call `show()` on all of them.
This is important, for two reasons:

1. `show()` overrides an explicit `hide()` or `setVisible(False)`, and that shouldn't happen);
2. removing an item from a layout isn't always effective, since the item's parent (widget or layout) won't change, and could result in unexpected behavior;

Also note that `sqrt` and `ceil` are already provided by the `math` module, which is part of the python standard library. Numpy is quite a big module, and if you don't need that for anything else you're going to add an important requirement which would ask for unnecessary resources (not only in memory, but also including install, if not even actual *building*).

In the following implementation I used an `iter()` to cycle through all widgets, so that there's no need for item indexing.

```py
from math import sqrt, ceil
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class MultiWidgetLayout(QGridLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setSpacing(0)
        self.setContentsMargins(1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.__widgets = []
        self.__lastLayout = QHBoxLayout()

    # ...

    def updateLayout(self):
        n = len(self.__widgets)
        columns = ceil(sqrt(n))
        rows, remain = divmod(n, columns)
        widgets = iter(self.__widgets)
        for r in range(rows):
            for c in range(columns):
                super().addWidget(next(widgets), r, c)
        self.removeItem(self.__lastLayout)
        if remain:
            self.addLayout(self.__lastLayout, rows, 0, 1, columns)
            for i in range(remain):
                self.__lastLayout.addWidget(next(widgets))
```

Comment: What if I want to clear all widgets in QGridLayout? How to fullfile this problem?

Comment: @QiangZhang if by "clear" you mean delete, then use `deleteLater()` on each of them, while also removing them from the list: `while self.__widgets: self.__widgets.pop().deleteLater()`; if you meant something else, please clarify.

Comment: The "clear" means remove all widgets included in QGridLayout. So that I can re-add widgets to this layout. I don't want to delete widgets.

Comment: Why do you need to "clear" the widgets and add them again?

Comment: For example, the user add widget1/widget2/widget3 in the layout. Then, user want to add only widget4/widget5 in the layout. So, we need to clear widget1/2/3 and re-add widget 4/5.

Comment: With this implementation, if you need to keep widgets that might be shown later, then create a list for hidden widgets, then call `setParent(None)` for each one you need to hide: the widget will be automatically removed from the layout and hidden until it's reinserted again.